# Are there unique camera bags designed for micro four-thirds?

Tags: camera-bag, micro-four-thirds

There are a lot of discussions about bags for DSLR — but since micro four thirds is all about size, there have to be some unique bags designed especially to take advantage of the reduced size. Using a SLR bag for Micro 4/3 equipment seems plain stupid.

Requirements: fit a camera, a bunch of lenses and some accessories (like extra battery / charger) plus a MacBook Air 11".

Comment: Seems to me a macbook air will be more of an issue than a micro 4/3 camera!

Comment: Yeah, it was the laptop fitting in there that got me confused too :)

Answer (score 7):

Well many a camera bag has interchangeable dividers that allow you to custom fit the interior compartments - so any of those *can* be a micro four thirds bag.  Since you're going to be throwing the whole kitchen sink your bag ("a camera, a bunch of lenses and some accessories (like extra battery / charger) plus a MacBook Air 11") there's little use in recommending a particularly small bag.   Just get the size and style of bag you want that has the movable dividers.

Answer (score 2):

Some smaller camera bags like the [Think Tank Retrospective 5](http://www.thinktankphoto.com/products/retrospective-5-pinestone.aspx) are marketed as being designed for MFT cameras, but that generally just means they're slightly smaller bags. As rfusca mentioned, pretty much any smaller bag with adjustable dividers should function.

Answer (score 1):

I've been buying (and selling my) camera-bags for years, (ThinkTank, Timbuk2, Lowepro, Dömke, Crumpler, brandless, you name it) only to discover that the best bag, the most practical one anyway, is the one I sort-of designed (for) myself in the end.
My main camera is also a m4-3 OMD by Olympus, which is really tiny compared to the big Canon full framers.

I took a really old lightweight smaller messenger-type shoulder-bag I don't even know the brand/model of, I think it's made by a German brand that also made tents of the same olive-army colored fabric, I got it in the early 1980s. Looks a lot like the one Jack Bauer wears in the first season of the 24-series. I had been using it to put my laptop (lenovo x230) inside, with a padded neoprene sleeve so it was safe no matter what bag I put it in, as long as it would fit against the back of the bag.
Then I put a foam bottom in the bag, which I got from some computer-part packaging I could easily cut to what I wanted for the rectangle-sized bottom. The rest, lenses, camera, I put inside several well-fitted neoprene pouches that I just put on top of the foam bottom, this was pretty good for my usage outdoors. A year later I extended the bottom-part upwards using a silicon-glue and a thinner sturdier foam (also sourced from some packaging material) so the inner sides of the bag would be a little more protected. Mainly because the lenses and camera would bounce around a little too much for my taste. Lastly I added 3 small dividers of a thin strong nylon material, also glued with silicon kit, and with that, I must add, it all has been working out just great for me. I don't really care about the looks of the inside of my bag, but I did use lighter colored foam and dividers, so it's all easy to find stuff inside.
The bag now weighs only 850 grams, all-in (but without content), which is still less than even the ones sold als 'lightweight'. Plus, it fits my laptop when I need it to.

While writing this I found someone who did a similar thing without extra padding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zNbJJTA-AY

Comment: By the way, the guy in the video shows off some really expensive neoprene pouches, which is mostly just paying for the brand, paying to be cool. You can buy similar quality for A LOT less on ebay from Japan or amazon from Germany, which I usually do to save on the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that such big manufacturer like Lowepro will have something to fit your needs. They have very good and modular bags and cases. Just have a look. As I wanted to buy some case to fit my DSLR with my Tamron 70-300 plus some additional lens, filters etc. - it was finally not a big problem and I quickly found their Inverse 100 AW. There are also other good brands like Caselogic or Kata. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use padded lunch bags for storing MFT gear in your regular bag. This opens up a whole world of options with far better designs than most camera cases.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a long time and found the Winer 9 and 9+.  It fits my Fuji X-T1 with 18-55, 60mm, and 55-200 plus extras.  Hard to find locally but its smaller thickness makes it perfect.